# In jquery can 'browser' use as selector like window and document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a statement run when the browser is closed like

```
$(window).unload(function() {
 //do statements
}
```

But i don't want only certain window is closed to do that but i want to do that when the whole browser is closed. If the browser can't use as selector can you give me other way to do what i want to happen?

Comment: It's not possible to distinguish between window closing and quitting the application.

Comment: YOu cannot reliably detect when a window, tab, or the entire browser, is being closed. you can *TRY* with onunload, but you can't ever depend on it.

Comment: There's a `$(browser).is('dead', function() {...` coming in jQuery 3

Comment: @adeneo I've heard it will support `.is('streaming-cat-videos')` as well, might come in handy.

Comment: @Jack - The future looks bright, I'm still waiting for the `<noporn> ` tag

Comment: oh i see.. thanks to all your reply